# Shiny.setInputValue is not a function error

Tags: r, shiny

I am baffled why the following code produces the "Shiny.setInputValue is not a function" error:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          shiny::tags$script(htmltools::HTML('
  quantityaa = 1;
  console.log(quantityaa);
  Shiny.setInputValue("hi", quantityaa);
                                  '))
       ,
       
        )
        )
        
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    hi <- reactive({ input$hi})
    print(hi)
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What is wrong with this code that produces this error? I cannot see anything wrong with it, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use shiny javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039338/how-to-use-shiny-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Shiny is not ready yet. Use the `shiny:connected` event:

```js
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {
  // your awesome JavaScript here can use Shiny.setInputValue
});
```